# $L^2$ function $f$ belongs to $L_k^2(\mathbb R^d)$ if and only if $(1+|\xi|^2)^{k/2}\hat{f}(\xi)$ belongs to $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

When I read stein's functional analysis book,there is a sentence saying that $L^2$ function $f$ belongs to $L_k^2(\mathbb R^d)$ if and only if $(1+|\xi|^2)^{k/2}\hat{f}(\xi)$ belongs to $L^2$,and that $||(1+|\xi|^2)^{k/2}\hat{f}(\xi)||_{L^2}$ is a Hilbert space norm equivalent to $||f||_{L_k^2(\mathbb R^d)}$ ,here $L_k^2(\mathbb R^d)$ denotes Sobolev space.I can't see how fourier transform play a role in it.Maybe I should use $(f,g)=(\hat{f},\hat{g})$ method in the equality of definition of weak derivatives?Does anyone know how to prove the statement

Comment: You have to use that $(\partial_{x_i} f)^\wedge(\xi) = c_n \xi_i \hat{f}(\xi)$, where $c_n$ is a constant depending on you normalization of the FT.

Comment: @Jose27 Now I have a very rough idea about how to prove the first part,but the second part,i.e. $||(1+|\xi|^2)^{k/2}\hat{f}(\xi)||_{L^2}=||f||_{L_k^2(\mathbb R^d)}$ where $||f||_{L_k^2(\mathbb R^d)}=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k} 
 ||\partial_x^{\alpha}f||_{L^2(\mathbb R^d)}$ is more hard to me,since the Sobolev space norm has servaral term to sum

Comment: You won't have equality with that norm on $L^2_k$, since that norm doesn't come from an inner product. Notice that Stein only claims *equivalence* of norms though; so you only have to show that the FT norm is bounded above an below by constant times the $L^2_k$ norm.